# how to clear the last <li> tag within a <ul>

Tags: css, xhtml

I know this is pretty basic, but it is giving me hangups.  I have a basic list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Insert Link Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Insert Link Here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Insert Link Here</a></li>
</ul>
```

What do I need to do to make sure the last `<li>` item gets cleared?  I've tried adding style="clear:both" to the end with no avail.  Also I've added a 'div' after the last `<li>` tag before the closing `</ul>` tag, that works, but I know it doesn't validate.

Comment: You may need additional 'assurances' like float:none, display:block for your 'li.clear' to make a difference to the regulars li's, you want to 'terminate'. With that, it becomes just as versatile like hr.clear in other div-ish context...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to have the background behind a block item which has only floated items inside, then:

```
ul {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This actually seems to be the easiest solution.  I removed the extra <li> element and added the class reference and it works.

Comment: Smashing solution. Saved me I don't know how much time!

Comment: Just learned something new! Very good and easy solution! Used the use the clearfix.

Comment: I can't believe how many times I have now found this answer after forgetting about it (definitely not a CSS guy).  Wish I could vote you up every time I end up here.

Comment: While this does have an effect, it generally adds a scrollbar which may be undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've found "[adding] a `div` after the last `<li>`...works" why not try adding another `<li>`, give it a class-name of, for example `clearing` and:

```
li.clearing {display: block; clear: both; }
```

If you need this to take up little, or no, room then adding `height: 0; background-color: transparent; border: 0 none transparent;` should prevent its being visible, while still causing the clearing to occur.

It would almost certainly be a benefit if you could add your use-case, and explain, as the comment asked: what do you want? (and I say that with trepidation, after watching too much Babylon 5 recently).

Comment: yep I did that. Oddly it didn't work inline '<li style="clear:both">' but if I just added <li class="clearing"> that seemed to work.  Thanks for the quick help

Comment: That is because li is an inline element, and the css supplied about converts it to a block element. clear:both; does work on an inline element.

Comment: @Jamestuddart, +1 for the explanation.