# Simple css example that breaks margin-bottom for <li> and I don't know why

Tags: html, css

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/74y7h/

When I float:left the item-content div, suddenly margin-bottom no longer works on each of the items in the list.  Remove the float:right line and re-run the code and you'll see the margins reappear between the list items.

Why is this happening?  I don't need a full lesson, but a simple one or two sentence explanation would be appreciated, not just the fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [how to clear the last <li> tag within a <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788131/how-to-clear-the-last-li-tag-within-a-ul)

Comment: My problem is the margin-bottom *between* list items, not at the bottom of the entire list.  I'm looking through the answers more thoroughly now, though, in case there's some indirect explanation I'm missing...

Comment: Ok, I see that this works, but don't really understand why.  I'm researching now.. is there a simple explanation?

Comment: Put a border on the `li`, and you'll see that it's height collapses to 0 when you float the contents. This is due to how inlining elements works (an element becomes inline when you float it). To get an element to *stretch* to fit inline elements, you need to use the `overflow: auto` technique.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  It appears that display:block can't override the inlining either.

Answer (score 1):

Apply overflow:hidden to the containing element (.item).  Give it a shot.  It works.  Applying the overflow (hidden or auto) triggers a new "block formatting context" for the containing div that doesn't run all over the floated elements.  I can't say I understand completely why it works, but it does (and it's different from hasLayout issues).

Comment: Thanks!  Bradley explains in the comments to his answer above why overflow:auto works.